# left outer join in sql need values from two tables values not coming

Tags: sql

i need values from two tables by using left outer join. 
my code

```
SELECT RR.RRID,
       RR.PROPERTYID,
       RR.ROOMTYPEID,
       RR.OCCID,
       RR.RATE,
       RT.ACCOUNTID,
       RR.CREATEDBY,
       RR.CREATEDDATE,
       RR.UPDATEDBY,
       RR.UPDATEDDATE,
       (OT.OCCID) AS TXOCCID,
       (OT.OCCUPANCY) AS TEXTOCCUPANCY,
       (RT.ROOMTYPEID) AS TXROOMTYPRID,
       (RT.TYPENAME) AS TEXTROOMTYPE 
FROM APP_ROOMRATE RR  
RIGHT OUTER JOIN TX_MYROOMTYPE RT ON RT.ROOMTYPEID = RR.ROOMTYPEID 
RIGHT OUTER  JOIN TX_MYOCCUPANCYTYPE OT ON OT.OCCID=RR.OCCID   
WHERE RT.ACCOUNTID=2
```

in this i am getting last table tx_occpancy values, i need to get the tx_roomtype values two from left outer join,

advance thanks

Comment: Which DBMS you are using?

Comment: Use first one as right join and second one as left join.

Comment: only i am getting TX_MYROOMTYPE values, if i am using left outer join no values coming , the same which you have mentioned values coming only for TX_MYROOMTYPE  , tx_occpancy values not coming

Comment: `WHERE RT.ACCOUNTID=2` changes the outer to an inner join for `TX_MYOCCUPANCYTYPE`, either change your join order (RT as the 'most' outer table) or move the condition into `ON`. If this will return a correct result depends on your actual needs.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the DDL + DML for the relevant tables and sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I see no left joins in your query, only right joins. Try replacing them with left joins and see what happens.

Comment: HI , used as left joins not getting values

Comment: only i am getting TX_MYROOMTYPE values, if i am using left outer join no values coming

Answer (score 0):

Replace second right outer join with left outer join.